# How do i start my service when sharing a audio file in another app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-manifest

im working on an android app and i need/want to share an audio file from another app and instantly start my service that displays a window over the other app

i tried using intent filters within my service like this:

```
 <service
            android:name=".FloatingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="specialUse"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <property
                android:name="android.app.PROPERTY_SPECIAL_USE_FGS_SUBTYPE"
                android:value="Foregroundservice to show user transcription of audio file they shared." />


        </service>
```

but my app isnt listed as a target for the share of a audio file (opus, mp3 etc)

when i start my service through an Activity it works but thats not what i need, i want the service e.g. the window it displays to show up without starting my Activity.

any help or nudges in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can only share to an activity. That activity can start the service. So, put your `<intent-filter>` on a suitable activity.

Comment: will this open up the Activity? is there no way how i could display my overlay window without switching to my app?

i appreciate your help!

Comment: "will this open up the Activity?" -- yes. "is there no way how i could display my overlay window without switching to my app?" -- the point of `Intent` actions like `ACTION_SEND` and `ACTION_VIEW` is to switch to the other app. You can create an activity that has no UI and finishes itself right away, though, to try to minimize the visual impact.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i will try it that way! if i get another solution ill answer it.

have a nice day/evening!

Answer (score 0):

@CommonsWare put me on the right track.

how i ended up doing it is this:

Create new Activity that recieves my intent, Launches my Service then finishes itself.

```
class ReceiveShareActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        handleIntent(intent)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        handleIntent(intent)
    }

    private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND && intent.type?.startsWith("audio/") == true) {
            //audio file was received
            val audioUri: Uri? = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)

            if (audioUri != null) {
                // Start FloatingService with a delay
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                    startFloatingService(audioUri)
                }, 500)
            }
        }

        // Finish the activity
        finish()
    }


}
```

then i added it to my manifest like:

```
     <activity
        android:name=".ReceiveShareActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now when i share a audio file (for example a voice message from Whatsapp) my Acticity gets launched but the

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

makes it so its invisible.

my Service gets launched and the Overlay i want to show is shown over the previous app.

Hope this will help someone in the future, and a big thanks to @CommonsWare